# How do I resolve Windows XP PC constant start up loop?

Tags: windows-xp

I had to fix something related to my disk defrag and I went ahead to MSConfig and switched the to start in Safe Mode, I pressed apply and restart it. I'm presented with the following options:

Safe Mode

Safe Mode with Networking

Safe Mode with Command Prompt

Last Known Good Configuration (your most recent settings that worked)

Start windows normally

Comment: Could you add a few more details? What happens when you select each one? Does it just reboot you again?

Comment: Yeah it previously just kept on rebooting the same way. Now after I did the repair set up, it does the chkdsk and afterwards keeps saying "Setup cannont continue because of Safe Mode. Setup will now restart".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though something has become corrupt related to your boot files.

Your easiest fix is to grab a windows xp sp3 install disk, boot from the CD and do a repair on the system. Make sure you're not installing a new system, just repairing it.

You can obtain an ISO of Windows XP SP3 here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25129

Comment: I tried to repair the system but it didn't seem to do the trick. I click enter then I click Repair. I've been told in the past to never go straight to the recovery console. Do you think I should go to the recovery console first?

Comment: As long as you don't do a full re-install you won't really lose anything. You can try to use System restore from the Recovery console (if memory serves me right).

Comment: I tried  running the recovery but it keeps going into safe mode and says "The Setup cannot run in Safe Mode. Set will restart now". I know exactly how the problem happened, I just really regret click start up in Safe Mode on MS Config.

Comment: You may want to check this tool out then. http://www.ubcd4win.com/ It should let you boot into Windows XP (make image from the CD you have, add it to the boot disk) then boot with the new CD, repair from there.

Comment: What do you mean "make image from the CD you have", you want me to download this onto a flashdrive/CD and then use it as my boot CD?

Comment: Read the instructions on the ubcd4win website.